# How to refer to a "selected object" using a UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, ivar

I want to use a tap gesture recognizer to select an object (a `UITextView` in my case here). When the object is tapped the `"recognizer.view"` will return what I think is the object being tapped. Below is what I get if I LOG the recognizer.view.

```
<UITextView: 0xf67afc0; frame = (155.5 119.5; 100 100); text = 'string'; clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xf67b1f0>;
```

I assume that I want to take the first value here: `UITextView: 0xf67afc0;` and apply that to a `UITextView` ivar. I set one up like so

```
UITextView *selectedTextView;
```

But when I try to assign `recognizer.view` to this ivar, I get an error: ! **`Incompatible pointer types assigning to "UITextView" __strong from "UIView".`** I guess I need to somehow take the first value only `UITextView: 0xf67afc0` and assign that to the ivar? How would I do that, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to downcast the `view` property on the recognizer to be a `UITextView` rather than a `UIView`.

```
UITextView *selectedTextView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
```

Hope this helps, if you have any questions let me know.